# Is it possible to use an interface with ES6 class getters, setters and private properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface

I am using TypeScript and I am trying to work out how to implement an interface in an class that uses ES6 getters and setters.

Is this possible? Using the code below highlights errors in the class.

For example:

> (property) SportsCar.make: string
> Property 'make' in type 'SportsCar' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Car'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ (make: string): string; (): void; }'.ts(2416)*

The code:

```
export interface Car {
    _make: string;
    _model: string;

    make(make: string): string; // for setter
    make(): void; // for getter
    
    model(model: string): string; // for setter
    model(): void; // for getter
}

class SportsCar implements Car {

  _make: string;
  _model: string;

  constructor(make:string, model: string) {
  } 

  set make(make: string) {
    this._make = make
  }

  get make() {
    return this._make
  }

  set model(model: string) {
    this._model = model
  }

  get model() {
    return this._model
  }
}

module.exports = SportsCar;
```

Using `getMake()` and `setMake()` instead of ES6 getters and setters works. But I would like to use ES6 class getters and setters if possible.

For example, this works:

```
export interface Car {
     _make: string;
    _model: string;

    setmake(make: string): void; // for setter
    getmake(): string; // for getter
    
    setmodel(model: string): void; // for setter
    getmodel(): string; // for getter
}

class SportsCar implements Car {

   _make: string;
   _model: string;

  constructor(make:string, model: string) {
  } 

  setmake(make: string) {
    this._make = make
  }

  getmake() {
    return this._make
  }

  setmodel(model: string) {
    this._model = model
  }

  getmodel() {
    return this._model
  }

}

module.exports = SportsCar;
```

Finally, when using an interface, is it possible to set class properties to private? Interfaces don't appear to allow you to define this and if using the code below I get the following error in VS Code.

The code:

```
export interface Car {
    _make: string;
    _model: string;

    setmake(make: string): void; // for setter
    getmake(): string; // for getter
    
    setmodel(model: string): void; // for setter
    getmodel(): string; // for getter
}

class SportsCar implements Car {

   private _make: string;
   private _model: string;

  constructor(make:string, model: string) {
  } 

  setmake(make: string) {
    this._make = make
  }

  getmake() {
    return this._make
  }

  setmodel(model: string) {
    this._model = model
  }

  getmodel() {
    return this._model
  }

}

module.exports = SportsCar;
```

**The error:**

*class SportsCar
Class 'SportsCar' incorrectly implements interface 'Car'.
Property '_make' is private in type 'SportsCar' but not in type 'Car'.ts(2420)*

Answer (score 2):

All of your things are possible. Look at this code:

```
export interface Car {
    make: string;
    model: string;
}

export class SportsCar implements Car {

   private _make: string;
   private _model: string;

  constructor(make:string, model: string) {
    this._make = make;
    this._model = model;
  }

  set make(make: string) {
    this._make = make
  }

  get make() {
    return this._make
  }

  set model(model: string) {
    this._model = model
  }

  get model() {
    return this._model
  }

}
```

You can try it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&module=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYUyjgG8AoOSuAW0wGtgAuOAZximQHMBuCq6iABNgAG2ZsOSHmQC+ZMqEiw42EZhYs4AZSUwWhYgmpgRwasBSaDpeVTAcAbplRwA+rQbj2XXncfO8dyFRL0lpPmwIJAkAV2wYaAAKDyYJLgAaGmCxVm8pAEobKjgYAAsEFgA6d3o8AF4aWt8qMorqgWEROAaO0Wa5PhZgeBTk2tCuQvJi1qqahm7Ghj4Byk5hpeBEqb5KKGGYqCQS8rmUldtWDd6RZOyJgqKW0-bsxZuLvnWR7O2nvYORxObSCnU+ciAA).

Comment: ok thanks. But this doesnt include the private properties within the interface. Not setting them as private in the class enables them to be included in the interface. But I need to make them private in the class. Is that not possible? Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot make private interface members. There are the two public properties, so why do you need to have the private ones in the interface?

Comment: In relation to the method you provided above, isnt the point of the interface to ensure that a class impliments all of the required functions, properties? Using the method above does not enforce both get and set versions of make and model. Adding only get make, and get model meets the requirements of the interface you defined. However, both are required. Is there a way around that?

Comment: No, that is not possible with interfaces. But I understand your problem

Comment: An interface can only describe the public properties of an object.  You could write an interface that describes explicit get and set functions with names like getMake and setMake if you wanted to do that.  This answer uses an interface with properties rather than functions.  They are not readonly, therefore the class that implements this interface **must** have a setter in order to properly implement it.

Comment: The point of an interface is to abstract the public interactions away from the implementation details.  You could just as well implement this interface with two public properties rather than private ones hidden behind getters and setters.  The point is that when you need to interact with a Car you should not care how it is implemented.  It could just as well be a plain object rather than a class.  Typescript is structurally typed which means if it has a make and a model it’s a Car.